# Flutter How to display a single list item per day?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, datetime, random

I have a list of String, and I'd like to display just one item per day at random. How can I do this with Flutter? Thanks

I think the right way is to use SharePreferences and DateTime, but I can't seem to do it. How can I do it? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There're many ways. I'll tell you that solution from my point of view:

- ***Input***: List of (I assume) quotes.
- ***Output***: Display **1** RANDOM quote per day.

**SOLUTION**:

**1/** Using 2 `SharePreferences` keys to store day and quote:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
// read data
int savedDay = prefs.getInt('savedDay') ?? 0;
String savedQuote = prefs.getString('savedQuote') ?? "";
```

**2/** Get current day using `DateTime`. Check if current day NOT equals to saved day (which means this is a new day and we need to re-new things), then get a new quote from the list and write data.

```
int currentDay = DateTime.now().day;
if (currentDay != savedDay) {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  // write data
  savedDay = currentDay;
  await prefs.setInt('savedDay', currentDay);
  savedQuotes = lstQuotes[Random().nextInt(lstQuotes.length)];
  await prefs.setString('savedQuotes', savedQuotes);
}
```

Good luck.